# Different between batch and batchAll functionality in Pallet Utility

Tags: pallet, frame

Two functions `batch` and `batch_all` are slightly similar

- batch: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/utility/src/lib.rs#L201
- batch_all: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/utility/src/lib.rs#L323

Questions:

- When to use `batch` and when to use `batch_all`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs of both mention the difference. For [`batch`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_utility/pallet/dispatchables/fn.batch.html) it is:

```
/// Send a batch of dispatch calls.
```

And for [`batch_all`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_utility/pallet/dispatchables/fn.batch_all.html) it is:

```
/// Send a batch of dispatch calls and atomically execute them.
```

So, when you send a batch with `batch` with 5 calls. The third call in the batch fails, the changes of the first two calls are not reverted and committed to the block. `batch_all` would rollback all changes done to the state. However, the user would still pay for the transaction even if all changes are rolled back.