# Utility pallet: What are the key differences between batch batch_all and force_batch

Tags: pallet, pallet-utility

*In [this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7911/different-between-batch-and-batchall-functionality-in-pallet-utility), and [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7917/116) the difference between `batch` and `batch_all` are discussed, but there is a third similar function in the utility pallet `force_batch`*

What are the key differences between `batch` `batch-all` and `force-batch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key differences are:

- `batch_all`: **Stops on error** and reverts everything (all-or-nothing).
- `force_batch`: **Does not stop** on error and only reverts the failed calls (keep-going).
- `batch`: **Stops on error** and only reverts the first failed call (fail-fast).

Comment: Your answer was a bit more on the spot I have accepted it.

Comment: Thanks. I think we should add your Q as FAQ to the pallet docs. It seems to come up often.

Comment: I'm using this in one of my projects, yet I fail to remember why and have to read it carefully every time.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

**batch**
*The [docs](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/pallet_utility/pallet/dispatchables/fn.batch.html) are not very helpful yet:*

> Send a batch of dispatch calls

**batch_all**

*Here the [doc](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/pallet_utility/pallet/dispatchables/fn.batch_all.html) give us some clue*

> Send a batch of dispatch calls and atomically execute them. The whole transaction will rollback and fail if any of the calls failed.

**force_batch**
*The [docs](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/pallet_utility/pallet/dispatchables/fn.force_batch.html) finally touches the key differences*

> Send a batch of dispatch calls. Unlike batch, it allows errors and won’t interrupt.

**So in short the key differences are:**

1. `batch` will run all parts until it encounters an error then stop
2. `batch_all` will run all parts but roll back all if there is an error
3. `force_batch` will continue execute the rest of the parts even if some part failed.